# Pullback and quadratic differentials on Riemann surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Suppose we have some meromorphic quadratic differential $q=\phi\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x^2$ on a punctured Riemann surface $\mathcal{C}$, and that $q$ is the pullback via a function $f$ of a meromorphic quadratic differential with three poles on the sphere $\mathbb{P}^1$:

$$q=f^*\left(\frac{\left(\mathrm{d}\zeta\right)^2}{4\pi^2\zeta\left(1-\zeta\right)}\right)$$

(For reference, I am looking at Theorem 6.5 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/9811024v2.pdf)).

My question is: just by using the definition of the pullback and the fact that $f^*\left(\mathrm{d}g\right)=\mathrm{d}\left(f^*g\right)$, can we then write:

$$q=\frac{\left(\mathrm{d}f\right)^2}{4\pi^2f\left(1-f\right)}$$

This seems innocuous from the definition of the pullback, but I am suspicious for two reasons: (a) I see the first equation in the literature a lot, but never the second; (b) something fishy happens in my subsequent calculations if I push through with this.

Should be a simple question to answer, but any help much appreciated!

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes, I now see that you are right. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is that *yes*, the second expression for $q$ above is fine. This expression follows from the definition of the pullback, and the problems I was encountering in later calculations were due to other issues.